# Gulp handle an array of files with gulp-rev

Tags: javascript, promise, gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-rev

#### Context

I have a `gulpfile.js`. It basicaly concats two folders with js files to two files to export to a dist folder. It also adds a cache buster and a uglified version for production.

```
//gulpfile.js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const maps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const gulpif = require('gulp-if');
const inlineCss = require('gulp-inline-css');
const jsValidate = require('gulp-jsvalidate');
const notify = require('gulp-notify');
const rev = require('gulp-rev');
const fs = require("fs");
const del = require('del');

const distFolder = './myapp/dist/';

/* Concat all scripts and add cache buster */
gulp.task('app_concatScripts', (done) => {
    /*first remove old app.js files */
    return del([distFolder + "app-*.{js,map}"])
        .then(paths => {
            /*Concat files with sourcemaps, hash them and write to manifest*/
            return gulp.src("./myapp/js/source-app/*.js")
                .pipe(maps.init())
                .pipe(concat({
                    path: "app.js",
                    cwd: '',
                    newLine: '; \n'
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder))
                .pipe(rev())
                .pipe(maps.write('./'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder))
                .pipe(rev.manifest(distFolder + 'rev-manifest.json', {
                    base: distFolder,
                    merge: true
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder));
        });

});

/* Minify scripts and add cache buster */
gulp.task('app_minifyScripts', (done) => {
    return gulp.src(distFolder + "app.js", {
            allowEmpty: true
        })
        .pipe(uglify())
        .on('error', notify.onError((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            return error.message + ' in ' + error.fileName;
        }))
        .pipe(rename("app.min.js"))
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder))
        .pipe(rev.manifest(distFolder + 'rev-manifest.json', {
            base: distFolder,
            merge: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder));
});

/* Concat all scripts and add cache buster, this function is exactly the same as app_concatScripts */
gulp.task('main_concatScripts', (done) => {
     /*Concat files with sourcemaps, hash them and write to manifest*/
    return del(["./myapp/dist/main-*.{js,map}"])
        .then(paths => {
            return gulp.src("./myapp/js/source-main/*.js")
                .pipe(maps.init())
                .pipe(concat({
                    path: "main.js",
                    cwd: '',
                    newLine: '; \n'
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder))
                .pipe(rev())
                .pipe(maps.write('./'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder))
                .pipe(rev.manifest(distFolder + 'rev-manifest.json', {
                    base: distFolder,
                    merge: true
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder));
        });
});

/* Minify scripts and add cache buster, this function is the same as app_minifyScripts */
gulp.task('main_minifyScripts', (done) => {

    return gulp.src("./myapp/dist/main.js")
        .pipe(uglify())
        .on('error', notify.onError((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            return error.message + ' in ' + error.fileName;
        }))
        .pipe(rename("main.min.js"))
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder))
        .pipe(rev.manifest(distFolder + 'rev-manifest.json', {
            base: distFolder,
            merge: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder));
});


/* watch task */
gulp.task('watch', (done) => {
    gulp.watch('./myapp/js/source-app/*.js', gulp.series('app_concatScripts', 'app_minifyScripts'));
    gulp.watch('./myapp/js/source-main/*.js', gulp.series('main_concatScripts', 'main_minifyScripts'));
    done();
});
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('main_concatScripts', 'main_minifyScripts', 'app_concatScripts', 'app_minifyScripts', 'watch'));
```

#### Output

The `gulpfile.js` works. It builds a `rev-manifest.json` like this:

```
{
  "app.js": "app-234318a58d.js",
  "app.min.js": "app-7788fee7f3.min.js",
  "main.js": "main-60788c863c.js",
  "main.min.js": "main-1e92517890.min.js",
  "style.css": "style-296f22c598.css",
  "admin.css": "admin-a3742ed2f6.css",
}
```

#### Problem

To get this working i copied the `_concatScripts` and `_minifyScripts` task for each js file: `app.js` and `main.js`. Making the gulpfile unnecessary large and hard to maintain.

#### What I have tried

I tried using an array to define scripts source files and output names. This does not work because the code in the loop block does not wait for the previous block to be ready. So the minify task fails sometimes because the original js file does not exists yet and sometimes the `rev-manifest.json` get overwritten by a previous code block.  So it is not really a gulp series anymore. What is the best practice to do something like this?

```
const scripts = [{
    name: 'app',
    source: './myapp/js/source-app/*.js'
}, {
    name: 'main',
    source: './myapp/js/source-main/*.js'
}];

/* Concat all scripts and add cache buster */
gulp.task('concatScripts', (done) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        var script = scripts[i];
        del([distFolder + script.name + "-*.{js,map}"])
            .then(paths => {
                /*Concat files with sourcemaps, hash them and write to manifest*/
                gulp.src(script.source)
                    .pipe(maps.init())
                    .pipe(concat({
                        path: script.name + ".js",
                        cwd: '',
                        newLine: '; \n'
                    }))
                    .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder))
                    .pipe(rev())
                    .pipe(maps.write('./'))
                    .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder))
                    .pipe(rev.manifest(distFolder + 'rev-manifest.json', {
                        base: distFolder,
                        merge: true
                    }))
                    .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder));
            });
    }

});

/* Minify scripts and add cache buster */
gulp.task('minifyScripts', (done) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        var script = scripts[i];
        gulp.src(distFolder + script.name + ".js", {
                allowEmpty: true
            })
            .pipe(uglify())
            .on('error', notify.onError((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                return error.message + ' in ' + error.fileName;
            }))
            .pipe(rename(script.name + ".min.js"))
            .pipe(rev())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder))
            .pipe(rev.manifest(distFolder + 'rev-manifest.json', {
                base: distFolder,
                merge: true
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder));
    }
});

/* watch task */
gulp.task('watch', (done) => {
    gulp.watch(['./myapp/js/source-app/*.js', './myapp/js/source-main/*.js'], gulp.series('concatScripts', 'minifyScripts'));
    done();
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('concatScripts', 'minifyScripts', 'watch'));
```

#### update

My gulp file now looks like this:

```
//gulpfile.js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const maps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const gulpif = require('gulp-if');
const inlineCss = require('gulp-inline-css');
const jsValidate = require('gulp-jsvalidate');
const notify = require('gulp-notify');
const rev = require('gulp-rev');
const fs = require("fs");
const del = require('del');
/* Concat all scripts and add cache buster */

const distFolder = './myapp/dist/';

function concatTask(opts) {
    const taskName = opts.name + '_concatScripts';
    gulp.task(taskName, (done) => {
        /*Concat files with sourcemaps, hash them and write to manifest*/
        return del(opts.del)
            .then(paths => {
                return gulp.src(opts.source)
                    .pipe(maps.init())
                    .pipe(concat({
                        'path': opts.name + '.js',
                        'cwd': '',
                        'newLine': '; \n'
                    }))
                    .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder))
                    .pipe(rev())
                    .pipe(maps.write('./'))
                    .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder))
                    .pipe(rev.manifest(distFolder + 'rev-manifest.json', {
                        'base': distFolder,
                        'merge': true
                    }))
                    .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder));
            });
    });
    return taskName;
}

function minifyTask(opts) {
    const taskName = opts.name + '_minifyScripts';
    gulp.task(taskName, (done) => {
        return gulp.src(distFolder + opts.name + '.js', opts.sourceParams)
            .pipe(uglify())
            .on('error', notify.onError((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                return error.message + ' in ' + error.fileName;
            }))
            .pipe(rename(opts.name + '.min.js'))
            .pipe(rev())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder))
            .pipe(rev.manifest(distFolder + 'rev-manifest.json', {
                'base': distFolder,
                'merge': true
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder));
    });
    return taskName;
}

const taskOptions = [{
    'name': 'main',
    'source': './myapp/js/source-main/*.js',
    'sourceParams': {
        'allowEmpty': false
    },
    'del': ['./myapp/dist/main-*.{js,map}']
}, {
    'name': 'app',
    'source': './myapp/js/source-app/*.js',
    'sourceParams': {
        'allowEmpty': false
    },
    'del': ['./myapp/dist/app-*.{js,map}']
},

 ];

const taskNames = taskOptions.map(opts => {
    return [concatTask(opts), minifyTask(opts)];
});
/* equivalent to defining tasks and assigning:
 *  var taskNames = [
 *    ['main_concatScripts', 'main_minifyScripts'],
 *    ['app_concatScripts', 'app_minifyScripts']
 *  ];
 */

gulp.task('watch', (done) => {
    taskOptions.forEach((opts, i) => {
        gulp.watch(opts.source, gulp.series.apply(gulp, taskNames[i]));
    });
    done();
});
/* equivalent to:
 *  gulp.task('watch', (done) => {
 *    gulp.watch('./myapp/js/source-main/*.js', gulp.series('main_concatScripts', 'main_minifyScripts'));
 *    gulp.watch('./myapp/js/source-app/*.js', gulp.series('app_concatScripts', 'app_minifyScripts'));
 *    done();
 *  });
 */

const allTaskNames = taskNames.reduce((arr, names) => arr.concat(names), []); // flatmap the task names into a single array
// console.log(allTaskNames.concat(['watch']));
/* equivalent to:
 *  let allTaskNames = ['main_concatScripts', 'main_minifyScripts', 'app_concatScripts', 'app_minifyScripts'];
 */

gulp.task('default', gulp.series.apply(gulp, allTaskNames.concat(['styles', 'watch'])));
/* equivalent to:
 *  gulp.task('default', gulp.series('main_concatScripts', 'main_minifyScripts', 'app_concatScripts', 'app_minifyScripts', 'watch'));
 */
```

The dynamic task creators work. Unfortunately the minify tasks are starting before the concatenation task are finished. I am getting the following error, adding the allowEmpty option does work, but then the wrong concatenated file gets minified:

```
[12:57:19] Using gulpfile /repo/myapp/gulpfile.js
[12:57:19] Starting 'default'...
[12:57:19] Starting 'main_concatScripts'...
[12:57:19] Finished 'main_concatScripts' after 47 ms
[12:57:19] Starting 'main_minifyScripts'...
[12:57:19] 'main_minifyScripts' errored after 11 ms
[12:57:19] Error: File not found with singular glob: /repo/myapp/dist/main.js (if this was purposeful, use `allowEmpty` option)
```

Comment: You should look at gulp-flatmap https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatmap or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746981/run-one-gulp-task-on-multiple-folders-the-folders-look-like-plugins-lsmwp/51750054#51750054

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a question of keeping the code [DRY](https://dzone.com/articles/is-your-code-dry-or-wet), you can write two functions containing generalisations of the WET code :

- `concatTask()`
- `minifyTask()`

Each of these funtions should define a gulp task and return an internally-generated task name.

```
function concatTask(opts) {
    const taskName = opts.name + '_concatScripts';
    gulp.task(taskName, (done) => {
        /*Concat files with sourcemaps, hash them and write to manifest*/
        return del(opts.del)
        .then(paths => {
            return gulp.src(opts.source)
            .pipe(maps.init())
            .pipe(concat({
                'path': opts.name + '.js',
                'cwd': '',
                'newLine': '; \n'
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder))
            .pipe(rev())
            .pipe(maps.write('./'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder))
            .pipe(rev.manifest(distFolder + 'rev-manifest.json', {
                'base': distFolder,
                'merge': true
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder));
        });
    });
    return taskName;
}

function minifyTask(opts) {
    const taskName = opts.name + '_minifyScripts';
    gulp.task(taskName, (done) => {
        return gulp.src(opts.source, opts.sourceParams)
        .pipe(uglify())
        .on('error', notify.onError((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            return error.message + ' in ' + error.fileName;
        }))
        .pipe(rename(opts.name + '.min.js'))
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder))
        .pipe(rev.manifest(distFolder + 'rev-manifest.json', {
            'base': distFolder,
            'merge': true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder));
    });
    return taskName;
}
```

Task definitions, watches and series executions can then be proceduralized as follows :

```
const taskOptions = [
    {
        'name': 'main',
        'source': './myapp/js/source-main/*.js',
        'sourceParams': {},
        'del': ['./myapp/dist/main-*.{js,map}']
    },
    {
        'name': 'app',
        'source': './myapp/js/source-app/*.js',
        'sourceParams': { 'allowEmpty': true },
        'del': ['./myapp/dist/app-*.{js,map}']
    }
];

const taskNames = taskOptions.map(opts => {
    return [concatTask(opts), minifyTask(opts)];
});
/* equivalent to defining tasks and assigning:
 *  var taskNames = [
 *    ['main_concatScripts', 'main_minifyScripts'],
 *    ['app_concatScripts', 'app_minifyScripts']
 *  ];
 */

gulp.task('watch', (done) => {
    taskOptions.forEach((opts, i) => {
        gulp.watch(opts.source, gulp.series.apply(gulp, taskNames[i]));
    });
    done();
});
/* equivalent to:
 *  gulp.task('watch', (done) => {
 *    gulp.watch('./myapp/js/source-main/*.js', gulp.series('main_concatScripts', 'main_minifyScripts'));
 *    gulp.watch('./myapp/js/source-app/*.js', gulp.series('app_concatScripts', 'app_minifyScripts'));
 *    done();
 *  });
 */

const allTaskNames = taskNames.reduce((arr, names) => arr.concat(names), []); // flatmap the task names into a single array
/* equivalent to:
 *  let allTaskNames = ['main_concatScripts', 'main_minifyScripts', 'app_concatScripts', 'app_minifyScripts'];
 */

gulp.task('default', gulp.series.apply(gulp, allTaskNames.concat('watch')));
/* equivalent to:
 *  gulp.task('default', gulp.series('main_concatScripts', 'main_minifyScripts', 'app_concatScripts', 'app_minifyScripts', 'watch'));
 */
```

*Barring mistakes, everything will happen in the same order as in the original code.*

What you end up with is not particularly self-explanatory. An understanding of [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) will certainly help.

Personally, I would leave the "equivalent to:..." comments in the deployed code as a reminder to oneself (and an explanation to others) of what is actually going on.

Comment: Thanks!! I played around with your snippet and get an error. Because the minify task runs before the concat task writes the concatenated file. See my updated Question. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to Roamer if figured to add another task for the deleting of js files. So one task can wait for another to be finished.  Here is the gulp file:

```
//gulpfile.js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const maps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const gulpif = require('gulp-if');
const inlineCss = require('gulp-inline-css');
const jsValidate = require('gulp-jsvalidate');
const notify = require('gulp-notify');
const rev = require('gulp-rev');
const fs = require("fs");
const del = require('del');
/* Concat all scripts and add cache buster */

const distFolder = './myapp/dist/';

function delTask(opts) {
    const taskName = opts.name + '_delScripts';
    gulp.task(taskName, (done) => {
        /*Delete old files*/
        return del(opts.del)

    });
    return taskName;
}

function concatTask(opts) {
    const taskName = opts.name + '_concatScripts';
    gulp.task(taskName, (done) => {
        /*Concat files with sourcemaps, hash them and write to manifest*/
        return gulp.src(opts.source)
            .pipe(maps.init())
            .pipe(concat({
                'path': opts.name + '.js',
                'cwd': '',
                'newLine': '; \n'
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder))
            .pipe(rev())
            .pipe(maps.write('./'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder))
            .pipe(rev.manifest(distFolder + 'rev-manifest.json', {
                'base': distFolder,
                'merge': true
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder));
    });
    return taskName;
}

function minifyTask(opts) {
    const taskName = opts.name + '_minifyScripts';
    gulp.task(taskName, (done) => {
        return gulp.src(distFolder + opts.name + '.js', opts.sourceParams)
            .pipe(uglify())
            .on('error', notify.onError((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                return error.message + ' in ' + error.fileName;
            }))
            .pipe(rename(opts.name + '.min.js'))
            .pipe(rev())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder))
            .pipe(rev.manifest(distFolder + 'rev-manifest.json', {
                'base': distFolder,
                'merge': true
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder));
    });
    return taskName;
}

const taskOptions = [{
    'name': 'main',
    'source': './myapp/js/source-main/*.js',
    'sourceParams': {
        'allowEmpty': false
    },
    'del': ['./myapp/dist/main-*.{js,map}']
}, {
    'name': 'app',
    'source': './myapp/js/source-app/*.js',
    'sourceParams': {
        'allowEmpty': false
    },
    'del': ['./myapp/dist/app-*.{js,map}']
}];

const taskNames = taskOptions.map(opts => {
    return [delTask(opts), concatTask(opts), minifyTask(opts)];
});
/* equivalent to defining tasks and assigning:
 *  var taskNames = [
 *    ['main_delScripts', 'main_concatScripts', 'main_minifyScripts'],
 *    ['app_delScripts', 'app_concatScripts', 'app_minifyScripts']
 *  ];
 */

gulp.task('watch', (done) => {
    taskOptions.forEach((opts, i) => {
        gulp.watch(opts.source, gulp.series.apply(gulp, taskNames[i]));
    });
    done();
});
/* equivalent to:
 *  gulp.task('watch', (done) => {
 *    gulp.watch('./myapp/js/source-main/*.js', gulp.series('main_delScripts', 'main_concatScripts', 'main_minifyScripts'));
 *    gulp.watch('./myapp/js/source-app/*.js', gulp.series('app_delScripts', 'app_concatScripts', 'app_minifyScripts'));
 *    done();
 *  });
 */

const allTaskNames = taskNames.reduce((arr, names) => arr.concat(names), []); // flatmap the task names into a single array
// console.log(allTaskNames.concat(['watch']));
/* equivalent to:
 *  let allTaskNames = ['main_delScripts', 'main_concatScripts', 'main_minifyScripts', 'app_delScripts', 'app_concatScripts', 'app_minifyScripts'];
 */

gulp.task('default', gulp.series.apply(gulp, allTaskNames.concat(['styles', 'watch'])));
/* equivalent to:
 *  gulp.task('default', gulp.series('main_delScripts', 'main_concatScripts', 'main_minifyScripts', 'app_delScripts', 'app_concatScripts', 'app_minifyScripts', 'watch'));
 */
```

And the output:

```
[16:40:31] Using gulpfile gulpfile.js
[16:40:31] Starting 'default'...
[16:40:31] Starting 'main_delScripts'...
[16:40:31] Finished 'main_delScripts' after 29 ms
[16:40:31] Starting 'main_concatScripts'...
[16:40:31] Finished 'main_concatScripts' after 84 ms
[16:40:31] Starting 'main_minifyScripts'...
[16:40:34] Finished 'main_minifyScripts' after 2.45 s
[16:40:34] Starting 'app_delScripts'...
[16:40:34] Finished 'app_delScripts' after 941 μs
[16:40:34] Starting 'app_concatScripts'...
[16:40:34] Finished 'app_concatScripts' after 58 ms
[16:40:34] Starting 'app_minifyScripts'...
[16:40:37] Finished 'app_minifyScripts' after 3.12 s
[16:40:37] Starting 'styles'...
[16:40:37] Finished 'styles' after 215 ms
[16:40:37] Starting 'watch'...
[16:40:37] Finished 'watch' after 19 ms
[16:40:37] Finished 'default' after 6.04 s
```

Comment: Florian, well done, I'm not sure I would have thought to add 'delete' tasks but that makes sense. A variation might be to rename rather than delete, which would give you files to which you could revert if the concat-minify process failed.

Comment: If you want, you can [control flow with Promises](https://fettblog.eu/gulp-promises/) instead of Gulp's internal 'series' mechanism. Personally, I would find the flow, and error handling, simpler to control that way.