# Capture and reuse a glob

Tags: sass, gulp

I am new to Gulp programming.

I need to define a "dynamic" scss task that compiles multiple source directories in multiple destination directories

- src/main/scss/

  - app.scss (global resource)
  - modules/ (modules resources)

    - admin/

      - *.scss
    - ftt/

      - *.scss

The above is the directory layout of the source files.
I am interested in compiling each set of scss files under modules directory (which I may not know in advance) into a directory tree that includes the module itself

```
src/main/scss/modules/admin/*.scss ==> webapp/secure/admin/common/common.css
src/main/scss/modules/ftt/*.scss==> webapp/secure/ftt/common/common.css
```

I can write a glob that captures `src/main/scss/modules/*/*.scss` but how to *reuse* the star representing the directory? If I was running regex I'd capture and use numbered group $1

Answer (score 1):

For a longer working code version of looping through an array of folders to build folder-based bundles, see [Processing arrays within Gulp to create bundles in each directory with ordered files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60156114/processing-arrays-within-gulp-to-create-bundles-in-each-directory-with-ordered-f/60163813#60163813)

---

I would suggest looking at glob.sync.  Do a search here for `[gulp] glob.sync user:836330`.  That's me.  I have answered a few questions here similar to yours.  See particularly [running a gulp task on separate folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746981/run-one-gulp-task-on-multiple-folders-the-folders-look-like-plugins-lsmwp/51750054#51750054).  It runs the same gulp task on different folders and then uses the folder names to set unique destinations.

[glob.sync](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#globsyncpattern-options) is great for something like this.

Pseudo code follows (**not tested**):

```
const moduleFolders = glob.sync('src/main/scss/modules');

// perhaps your app.scss is supposed to be bundled into each module's css?
// if so, just add a second source to the gulp.src below

const sassSrc = 'common.scss';  // or your main scss file that does the imports in each module

gulp.task('default', () => {

  let stream;

  // work on each folder separately
  moduleFolders.forEach(function (module) {

    stream = gulp.src( module + sassSrc )
      .pipe(sass())
      //.pipe(concat('style.min.css'))
      //.pipe(autoprefixer())
      //.pipe(cssmin())
      .pipe(gulp.dest( "webapp/secure/" + module + '/common' ));
  });
  return stream;
});
```