# Processing arrays within Gulp to create bundles in each directory with ordered files

Tags: javascript, gulp

Like most I have been concatenating my JS/CSS files into one big file within Gulp, however, with HTTP2 becoming the norm nowadays I thought I would change my gulp file instead to make related "bundles" instead, however am wondering how to manage this in a clean fashion within Gulp.

**My prior gulpfile.js:**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

var site_url = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx.local';

// Set some paths

var js_scripts = [
    'js/dev/lib/**/*.js',
    'js/dev/plugins/**/*.js',
    // We have to set the bootstrap lines separately as some need to go before others
    'js/dev/bootstrap/alert.js',
    'js/dev/bootstrap/collapse.js',
    'js/dev/bootstrap/tooltip.js',
    'js/dev/bootstrap/popover.js',
    'js/dev/bootstrap/tab.js',
    'js/dev/bootstrap/transition.js',
    'js/dev/custom.js'
];

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(js_scripts)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));
});

gulp.task('uglify', gulp.series('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(js_scripts)
        .pipe(gulpif('!**/*.min.js', uglify({mangle: false})))
        .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));
}));

// create a task that ensures the `uglify` task is complete before
// reloading browsers
gulp.task('js-watch', gulp.series('uglify', function (done) {
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
}));

/* Creates the standard version */

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

/* Creates the minified version */

gulp.task('css-minify', gulp.series('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(sass({
                outputStyle: 'compact' // Options: nested, expanded, compact, compressed
            }).on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(postcss([
                autoprefixer({
                    cascade: false
                }),
            ]))
            .pipe(cleanCSS({
                advanced: false,
                aggressiveMerging: false
            }))
            .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'));
}));

gulp.task('browser-sync', function(done) {
    browserSync.init({
        open: 'external',
        proxy: site_url,
        host: site_url,
        // port: 5000,
        browser: "chrome",
    });
    done();
});

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('browser-sync', function() {
    gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series('css-minify'));
    gulp.watch('js/dev/**/*.js', gulp.series('js-watch'));
}));

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('js-watch', 'css-minify'));
```

Now, to help turn the JS files into bundles I have made a change to the `js_scripts` array, to:

```
var js_scripts = [
    [
        'lib',
        [
            'js/dev/lib/**/*.js'
        ],
        ['lib.js', 'lib.min.js']
    ],
    [
        'plugins',
        [
            'js/dev/plugins/**/*.js'
        ],
        ['plugins.js', 'plugins.min.js']
    ],
    [
        'bootstrap',
        [
            // We have to set the bootstrap lines separately as some need to go before others
            'js/dev/bootstrap/alert.js',
            'js/dev/bootstrap/collapse.js',
            'js/dev/bootstrap/tooltip.js',
            'js/dev/bootstrap/popover.js',
            'js/dev/bootstrap/tab.js',
            'js/dev/bootstrap/transition.js',
        ],
        ['bootstrap.js', 'bootstrap.min.js']
    ],
    [
        'custom',
        [
            'js/dev/custom.js'
        ],
        ['custom.js', 'custom.min.js']
    ],
];
```

With the idea being that we will loop through this array and create a separate JS + min.js file for each.

Now, the problem is I'm not sure how to achieve this in Gulp in a *clean* way.

**Take this for example:**

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(js_scripts)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));
});
```

Ideally it would be good to loop through the array in here; but I'm not sure how to handle doing this multiple times, because once you `return` the first result then obviously the loop is going to end.

Does Gulp need to return each time? ...if not, then what do you return once you have finished processing the loop?

Answer (score 1):

I tried using `gulp-order` to force ordering of the bootstrap files but it was unreliable.  Here I use `merge2` instead - it seems to work much better.  Assumes you now have a `custom` folder.

[I didn't incorporate your `sourcemaps` pipes and browserSync reloads for brevity.]

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');

// const rename = require('gulp-rename');  // not needed
// var gulpif = require('gulp-if');        // not needed

var terser = require('gulp-terser');      // better than uglify, works with es6
const merge2 = require('merge2')          // does the ordering of source files
const glob = require('glob');
const path = require('path');

// glob.sync will build your array for you, so you don't need your 'js_scripts' array

const bundleFolders = glob.sync('js/dev/*/'); // returns an array of folders
console.log(bundleFolders);

gulp.task('scripts', () => {

  let stream;

  for (const bundle of bundleFolders) {

    // get just the last directory of 'js/dev/bootstrap', 'js/dev/lib`, etc.
    let thisBundle = path.basename(bundle);
    console.log('thisBundle = ' + thisBundle);

    if (thisBundle === 'bootstrap') {

      stream = merge2(

        gulp.src([
          'js/dev/bootstrap/alert.js',
          'js/dev/bootstrap/collapse.js',
          'js/dev/bootstrap/tooltip.js',
          'js/dev/bootstrap/popover.js',
          'js/dev/bootstrap/tab.js',
          'js/dev/bootstrap/transition.js',
        ])
          // your other stuff - sourcemaps, etc.
          .pipe(concat(thisBundle + '.js'))
          // your other stuff - sourcemaps, etc.
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js')));
    }

    else {  // not 'bootstrap' directory

      stream = gulp.src(bundle + "**/*.js")
        // your other stuff - sourcemaps, etc.
        .pipe(concat(thisBundle + '.js'))
        // your other stuff - sourcemaps, etc.
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));
    }
  }

  return stream;
});

// gulp.task('uglify', gulp.series('scripts', function () {  // not needed

gulp.task('terser', () => {

  let bundles= [];

  for (const bundle of bundleFolders) {

    // get `js/dev/custom/custom.js`,'js/dev/bootstrap/bootstrap.js' etc.
    bundles.push(bundle + path.basename(bundle) + '.js');
  }

  console.log(bundles);


  return gulp.src(bundles)

      // .pipe(gulpif('!**/*.min.js', uglify({mangle: false})))

      //  assumes what you want to uglify and concat are the 'lib.js', bootstrap.js', etc. files 

    .pipe(terser({ mangle: false }))    
    .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))    
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));
});

// create a task that ensures the `terser` task is complete before
// reloading browsers
// gulp.task('js-watch', gulp.series('terser', function (done) {
//   browserSync.reload();
//   done();
// }));

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('browser-sync', function () {

  gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series('css-minify'));

  // gulp.watch('js/dev/**/*.js', gulp.series('js-watch'));    // replaced by below
  gulp.watch('js/dev/**/*.js', gulp.series('scripts', 'terser', browserSync.reload));
}));


exports.terser = gulp.series('terser');    // useful for testing
exports.scripts = gulp.series('scripts');  // useful for testing

exports.default = gulp.series('scripts');  // just for testing
```

Comment: Awesome - thanks. No issues putting the `custom.js` in a folder of it's own; my only question is, how do I handle the bootstrap files where I mentioned in the comments that I need them to be processed in a certain order?

Comment: Thanks for that. I started testing this out, but ran into some problems..... seems to have had some syntax errors, but think I fixed those. Tested it just on the "scripts" task but got this error: _The following tasks did not complete: default, js-watch, uglify, scripts. Did you forget to signal async completion?_ - lastly, is there no need to include the `concat` call now or did you leave it out for brevity?

Comment: I just left out your pipes for brevity.  I used this form of returning the stream with no async warning before.  Do you get that warning if you run only the `scripts` task.

Comment: Oh ok.... reason I was asking if I still needed to include the `concat` call was because I wasn't sure how to now set the filename; as you can see I previously set it to `scripts.js`, but now the filename will be dynamic what do I put there instead? Does `bundle` represent the folder? Is it a string and would `contact(bundle + '.js')` work? As to your other question, yep, just running the `scripts` task throws the same type of errors.

Comment: I extensively revised the code, I couldn't get gulp-sort to work.  I tested the code.  Try it in parts to get going.   Run `gulp scripts` first, then `gulp terser` to see if you get the files you expect in your directories.

Comment: Sorry, haven't had a chance to test this yet, but just looking it over - wondering why you no longer use the `gulp-if`? In the `terser` task it seems you operate on the files generated by the `scripts` task rather than run through the individual files - problem there is there may be already compressed files within these bundled files, so I think it would be cleaner to run through each file again to create the respective bundle `*.min.js` files to avoid double compressing already minified files?

Comment: The terser pipe has this source: `return gulp.src(bundles)` which are the ``js/dev/custom/custom.js`,'js/dev/bootstrap/bootstrap.js, js/dev/lib/lib.js`,etc.' files only - the bundles.  They will not contain any already minified files (unless you put that functionality into your `scripts` tasks for some reason).  I don't see a need to pre-minify any files until after you make the bundles and then terser those.

Comment: Oh - well sometimes I will be including pre-minified files; such as jQuery may be included; I prefer to utilise their already minified version than create my own; so in this case, we have to avoid re-compressing them and hence run through the original files again. I'm sure I can work out how to do it based off your example in the `scripts` task, but thought you may want to update your answer :)

Comment: Been testing this and working well; though it was creating the files in the wrong place; needed to change the `gulp.dest()` back to `gulp.dest('./js')`.

Comment: Happy to accept this answer with the changes made... :)