# Gulp - run another task for every file from src collection

Tags: gulp

I have simple task to generate multiple themes from LESS files.

```
gulp.task("themes-base", function () {
    return gulp
        .src(["./build/THEMES/*Theme.less"])
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer()]))
        .pipe(chmod(666))
        .pipe(rename(function (path) {
            path.dirname += "/" + path.basename + "_New";
            path.basename = "styles";
            path.extname = ".css";
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/Content/Themes"));
});
```

Simply get all files from source directory and based on file name create output directory and put in compiled css.

```
Get AAATheme.less and compile it to Themes/AAA/styles.css  
Get BBBTheme.less and compile it to Themes/BBB/styles.css
```

It works fine.

But now I need for every processed LESS file copy resources (images, fonts, ...) from static folder to theme folder.

```
Get everything from build/Images folder and copy all to Themes/AAA/Images
Get everything from build/Images folder and copy all to Themes/BBB/Images
```

So every theme will have the same resources in own folder.

How can I create task to be able resolve destination directory structure to copy all resources after "gulp.dest"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, e.g., [run the same task on  multiple folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746981/run-one-gulp-task-on-multiple-folders-the-folders-look-like-plugins-lsmwp/51750054#51750054).

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const glob = require('glob');

// this gets an array of matching folders
const themeFolders = glob.sync('Themes/*/');
// console.log(themeFolders);

gulp.task('copy', () => {

  let stream;

  // work on each folder separately
  themeFolders.forEach(function (themeFolder) {

    stream = gulp.src( 'build/**/*' )
      // do other stuff here is you want
      .pipe(gulp.dest( themeFolder ));
  });
  return stream;
});
```

This is a powerful technique that is good to know.  I didn't consider the case where you have a Theme folder with no styles.css file in it - but those folders could be filtered out if need be.

Comment: thnx, I'll try this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Just use task `copy` and `/**/*` for directories and sub directories.

```
gulp.task('copy', function () {
    gulp.src('./build/Images/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./Themes/AAA/Images'));
});
```

for dynamic

```
gulp.task('copy', function () {
  return gulp.src('./build/Images/**/*')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
        path.dirname += "/"+path.basename;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/Content/Themes'));
});
```

Comment: dest folder names are dynamic based on src file names. I need to use original path resolving.